# Ngrok issue: Failed to update message endpoint with https://7df3-103-99-202-239.ngrok.io/api/messagesDetailed

Tags: visual-studio-code, bots, botframework, microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

I am not able to re-run my bot project on VS code, I am getting error ---- "[Error] - code:BT.MessageEndpointUpdatingError, message: Failed to update message endpoint with https://1005-103-99-202-239.ngrok.io/api/messages Suggestions: Please check log in output channel and try to fix this issue. Please retry the current step" as I have updated the ngrok url to debug the code locally.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pt4w.png)

Comment: ngrok has a local page you can browse to (http://127.0.0.1:4041) that lets you see all incoming messages and their responses - that could help indicate the error. If you see -nothing-, that's also useful as it helps show the calls are not arriving, so you've configured something incorrectly.

Comment: Have you browse the 127.0.0.1:4041. and check the error which you are getting.